# Java Homebrew installation

Tags: ruby, macos, command-line, homebrew

I am trying to install Homebrew on my Mac, for use with Java development. I have followed the instructions at: https://brew.sh, and pasted the command: `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"` into my terminal.

When I do this, a few scripts are executed, and I get the output:

```
MacBook-Pro:~ me$ /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

==> This script will install:

/usr/local/bin/brew

/usr/local/share/doc/homebrew

/usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1

/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew

/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/brew

/usr/local/Homebrew

Press RETURN to continue or any other key to abort

==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/mkdir -p /Library/Caches/Homebrew

Password:

==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod g+rwx /Library/Caches/Homebrew

==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/chown me /Library/Caches/Homebrew

==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...

remote: Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0

HEAD is now at ea8be17 Merge pull request #2631 from GauthamGoli/audit_homepage_rubocop

==> Cleaning up /Library/Caches/Homebrew...

==> Migrating /Library/Caches/Homebrew to /Users/me/Library/Caches/Homeb

==> Deleting /Library/Caches/Homebrew...
```

> Already up-to-date.
>
> Error: Could not link:
>
> /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/brew
>
> Please delete these paths and run `brew update`.
>
> Error: Failed to link all completions, docs and manpages:
>
> Permission denied - (../../../Homebrew/completions/zsh/_brew_cask, /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew_cask)
>
> Failed during: /usr/local/bin/brew update --force
>
> MacBook-Pro:~ me$

So the output is telling me that it's already up-to-date, presumably because I've already tried installing it once or twice?

How can I delete the paths to run `brew update`, like it's telling me to?

Comment: Did you intend to tag this with `ruby`?

Comment: "How do I delete a directory" really has nothing to do with [tag:ruby] (unless you are asking how to delete a directory from Ruby?) and really not a programming question at all, it seems more suitable for [su].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered this error. The fix is to run the command `sudo chown -R $USER:admin /usr/local/*` as described on the [Tech Stacker blog post that solves this issue](https://techstacker.com/brew-error-failed-to-link-all-completions-docs-and-manpages-permission-denied/).